# How to run an infinite loop program on startup on a Raspberry Pi without halting boot up

Tags: linux, shell, script, raspberry-pi, infinite-loop

I have a shell script which runs a program in an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while sudo /home/pi/MyCode; do :; done
echo Error with MyCode
```

I want to set up the shell script to run at start-up (which I've done with other bash scripts). However, I don't want the script to halt start-up, or prevent me from being to ssh in.

I've seen a lot of people who have had to wipe and remount their SD cards due to infinite loops being created on start-up.

How do I prevent this?

I've tried augmenting the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while sudo /home/pi/MyCode &; do :; done
echo Error with MyCode
```

to run MyCode in the background, but I keep getting an error along the lines

> unexpected character before ;

Is there a way to run this script on startup without halting my startup? If so, can it be done in a way that I still have the option of SSH'ing and stopping the script at any time?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question. I don't have a ' before the #!. #!/bin/bash is the fist line of my bash script.

Comment: I made a type. I meant a `/`, which appears to be gone now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:`

It generates the syntax error.

Alternatively insert a sleep 1 or something similar instead of it, bash can freak out on empty `while ... do` loops. If you go with this approach you should also lose the and if you leave it in you will create a new process for every iteration of the loop, grinding your pi to a halt once all your ram is taken.

Also use `./myCode.sh` or `exec myCode.sh` to be sure it actually runs the script.

If you are running Raspbian I would also suggest using upstart. This allows for a more controlled way of triggering stuff during boot, like only run once the filesystem is available.

Maybe post the code you want to run also, I can check if there are no other errors. Good for my bash-fu training!

Comment: I had this code running for 36 hours straight without error, so I don't think the : is giving me any problems. However, the code is driving an external piece of hardware, and giving it a second of rest would not be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop in its own script, running in the background:

The startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mainloop.sh &
echo Should get here
```

`mainloop.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while sudo /home/pi/MyCode; do :; done
```

There's probably a way to do this in one script, I'm not familiar enough with Bash to do it though.